# How do I obtain the conclusion from these premises?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

In my discrete math class, we were asked to obtain the conclusion from the following premise.

The student is either studying discrete mathematics or playing a board game.
He is not playing a board game.
If he is studying, he is getting a higher grade in discrete mathematics.

So I tried translating them into symbols

```
p v q
~q
p -> r
----
?
```

It's quite confusing for me on what the conclusion should be, should be it just r? (He got high grades?)

Or should be it like this,

```
p -> r 
r (He got High Grades)
---
p (Then he is studying.)
```

Comment: Correct, it must be $r$. From the two first premises you get $p$ and with it, from the third one, you get the conclusion.

Comment: Oh okay, so my first solution was correct all along?
p -> r
then r
`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should just be r.

For example,

p v q implies either p or q.
But we are given ~q.
Therefore p is true.
We know if p is true, then r is true.
Therefore, r is true.

Answer:
r.